# How to create a node only in case if it not exists in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a query which creates the entity.
I need something like `IF NOT EXISTS` in SQL. 
I checked to CREATE UNIQUE command but it's deprecated now.

Comment: See [Merge](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-node-derived)

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate question, which is why I am not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use MERGE statement to only create a node if it does not exist yet in the graph. Check the [documenation](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/)

```
MERGE (p:Person{name:"Marina"})
```

This will search for a node labelled Person with a name property "Marina" and if it does not find one it will create a new node with that label and name property.

If you want to create some other nodes if your original nodes does not exist then you need `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person{name:"Marina"})
// filter when the "Marina" node doesn't exist yet
WITH p WHERE p IS NULL
...
```

Comment: Down vote because you answered a question that is a duplicate without checking for the duplicate and using a close vote. I even noted that in a comment.

Comment: I don't think answering a duplicate question is enough to be downvoted. I also disagree about this whole duplicate obsession. It's very nice have more than one question talking about the same problem. A lot of times there is different information and details that were not included in the "original" question. To me, duplicate or not, all questions are valid.
When you search for a problem and its solution, the terms used will lead you to one or another question and its answers. Would not be great if all the questions, duplicate or not, have nice answers?
I will upvote it, because it's valid.